# Should one create interaction terms when clustering

Tags: clustering

I have a large set of feature vectors (>10^6) I would like to cluster. Each vector has only 4 numerical features. However I know they are correlated.  Should I create interaction terms before performing any clustering?  More generally, what is the best practice for clustering such data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you had a simple 2d data set with variables X and Y.

Now asume you added a third variable Z=X which is "correlated" to X (here: identical).

Then in any distance based algorithm (for Euclidean and similar distances) this is equivalent to putting double weight on X over Y.

In general, it *is* important to weight attributes properly, taking correlations into account. This cannot be done fully automatic because the program does not know which features/correlationd are important, and which can be ignored.

Why don't you just try different versions and *carefully* analyze which result is most interesting?

- raw data
- normalized data
- standardized data
- first two principal components